# Dictionary using distinct characters as values

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, distinct-values

I need to make a dictionary using the string list as keys and their distinct characters as values.

I have tried some functions and ended up with the following code but I cannot seem to add the string key into it

```
value=["check", "look", "try", "pop"]
print(value)
def distinct_characters(x):
    for i in x:
        yield dict (i=len(set(i)))
print (list(distinct_characters(value))
```

I would like to get

```
{ "check" : 4, "look" : 3, "try" : 3, "pop" : 2}
```

but I keep getting

```
{ "i" : 4, "i" : 3, "i" : 3, "i" : 2}
```

Comment: Your function will return a list of dicts, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, string is itself an iterable, so don't call list on dicts instead call dict on list of tuples like below.

```
value=["check", "look", "try", "pop"]
print(value)
def distinct_characters(x):
    for i in x:
        yield (i, len(set(i)))
print(dict(distinct_characters(value)))
```

Output:

```
{'check': 4, 'look': 3, 'try': 3, 'pop': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple dictionary comprehension:

```
value = ["check", "look", "try", "pop"]
result = {key: len(set(key)) for key in value}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies 
I needed to answer it as a function for a class exercise so I ended up using this code:

```
value=["check", "look", "try", "pop"]
print(value)
def distinct_characters(x):
    for i in x:
        yield (i, len(set(i)))
print(dict(distinct_characters(value)))
```

Thanks again